# One Form with one Modal and 1 input

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have this form with 2 buttons. The first button when you click it searches the SQL database on what you have placed on the `<input value`, and then it appears on the screen. The other button when you click `Create new Customer` it's a modal that fades. The issue here is when I place in the same `form` the modal and the `<input>` it only works the button `Create new Customer`. Any suggestions why?

```
  <div class="container mt-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="searchDatabase">

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" value="<?=$hasSearch?>" placeholder="Quick Search:">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="button1" class="btn btn-primary">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z"/>
        </svg> Search
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitDatabase">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zM6 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm6 5c0 1-1 1-1 1H1s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C9.516 10.68 8.289 10 6 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10zM13.5 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
        </svg>
        Create New Customer
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="submitDatabase" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="submitDatabase" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create new User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-row mb-4">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="First name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="lastname"  placeholder="Last name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email"  placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control"  name="telephone"  placeholder="Telephone" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger mt-1 float-right ml-1" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-success mt-1 float-right">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```